# ms access sum distinct date but group by quarter

Tags: sql, ms-access

Need help with following query

At moment displays a list of users with "Work Hours" grouped by Yearly Quarter.
I would also like to sum by worked Days - issue is that there can be more than one
row for each day, so the sum on "onsitedate" is incorrect.
I cant group by "day" beacuse the results need to show by yearly quarter.

sql

```
SELECT 
  username,
  DatePart ('q', [onsitedate]) AS [qtr],
  SUM(onsitehours),
  SUM(onsitedate)
FROM
  clocktable 
WHERE onsitedate BETWEEN #2013-01-01# AND #2013-12-31#
GROUP BY username, DatePart('q',[onsitedate]) 
ORDER BY username, DatePart('q',[onsitedate])
```

let me know if more info needed and TQ

UPDATE

as noted I should be using COUNT on sitedate line (typo)

```
SELECT 
  username,
  DatePart ('q', [onsitedate]) AS [qtr],
  SUM(onsitehours),
  **COUNT(onsitedate)**
FROM
```

however if two records exist for same date then i would like the count to be 1

example data is below:

```
username        onsitedate         onsitehours
-----------------------------------------------
bob             01/09/2013         10
bob             01/09/2013         2
fred            01/09/2013         12
jim             01/09/2013         10
jim             02/09/2013         5
```

required rs

```
username    qtr    onsitedate_count         onsitehours_sum
--------------------------------------------------------- 
bob         3      1                        12
fred        3      1                        12
jim         3      2                        15
```

as you can see - although there are two records for bob on 01/09/2013 the onsitedate_count is still 1
because they are the same day

also tried following so that days are grouped first, but no joy

```
GROUP BY tech_name, DatePart('d',[on_site_date]), DatePart('q',[on_site_date])
```

Comment: Have you tried using `COUNT(onsitedate)` instead of `SUM(onsitedate)`?

Comment: Hi,
COUNT is what i should be using, however this produces an incorrect result - if two records exist for same day the total will be 2, and I want the count to be 1 - have updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a query to sum the `onsitehours` for each combination of `username` and `onsitedate`.

```sql
SELECT 
    username,
    DatePart ('q', [onsitedate]) AS [qtr],
    onsitedate,
    SUM(onsitehours) AS SumOfonsitehours
FROM
    clocktable 
WHERE onsitedate BETWEEN #2013-01-01# AND #2013-12-31#
GROUP BY username, DatePart('q',[onsitedate]), onsidedate;
```

Then use it as a subquery and count the dates and sum the hours again for each combination of `username` and `qtr`.

```sql
SELECT
    sub.username,
    sub.qtr,
    Count(sub.onsitedate) AS onsitedate_count,
    Sum(sub.SumOfonsitehours) AS onsitehours_sum
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            username,
            DatePart ('q', [onsitedate]) AS [qtr],
            onsitedate,
            SUM(onsitehours) AS SumOfonsitehours
        FROM
            clocktable 
        WHERE onsitedate BETWEEN #2013-01-01# AND #2013-12-31#
        GROUP BY username, DatePart('q',[onsitedate]), onsitedate
    ) AS sub
GROUP BY sub.username, sub.qtr
ORDER BY sub.username, sub.qtr;
```

With your `clocktable` sample data, that query returns your requested output in Access 2007.

Answer (score 0):

just don't SUM(onsitedate). If I understant your question corretly

```
SELECT 
 a.username,
 DatePart ('q', a.[onsitedate]) AS [qtr],
 COUNT(b.[onsitedate]) onsitedate_count,
 SUM(a.onsitehours)
FROM clocktable a
  join (SELECT username, [onsitedate])
        FROM clocktable GROUP BY username,[onsitedate]) b
    on a.username = b.username
WHERE a.onsitedate BETWEEN #2013-01-01# AND #2013-12-31#
GROUP BY a.username, DatePart('q',a.[onsitedate]), b.onsitedate_count
ORDER BY a.username, DatePart('q',a.[onsitedate])
```

Comment: Hi - if i dont COUNT(onsitedate) then I wont get count of days worked
ps - example should have been COUNT (not sum) apologies

Comment: use the subquery then. I've edited the query. See above. hope it hepls

Comment: If you invest the effort to fix the syntax errors in that query, you will discover it returns onsitedate_count = 2 for bob.

Comment: thanks @HansUp for pointing it out. I guess I shouldn't hurry to much :)

Comment: You're welcome, but the latest revision still won't run in Access.  The following version runs without syntax errors in Access 2007, but is still logically flawed because it counts the same date (01/09/2013) twice for username bob ...

Comment: `SELECT 
 a.username,
 DatePart ('q', a.[onsitedate]) AS [qtr],
 b.onsitedate_count,
 SUM(a.onsitehours)
FROM clocktable a
 inner join (SELECT username, COUNT([onsitedate]) AS onsitedate_count
        FROM clocktable GROUP BY username) b
    on a.username = b.username
WHERE a.onsitedate BETWEEN #2013-01-01# AND #2013-12-31#
GROUP BY a.username, DatePart('q',a.[onsitedate]), b.onsitedate_count
ORDER BY a.username, DatePart('q',a.[onsitedate]) `

Comment: o yeah. Thanks again @HansUp. But I notied you provided already correct answer. sorry for budding in.